# Colour change on exposure to singlet oxygen?

Tags: oxidation-state, color, toxicity

Is there a dye that is particularly well suited to radical colour change on interaction with singlet oxygen, preferably non-toxic?

Based on this answer: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/27633/41616 some compounds, such as tetraphenylcyclopentadienone, seem to lose their colour intensity, but what about changing / inducing colours completely, and what is the proper term for this process (chromism?) called?

Comment: Lookup dye degradation. But the challenge is to find something that is only oxidized by singlet oxygen. The problem is that there are superoxide or hydroperoxy radicals that can do the job and you may not be able to figure out whether the singlet oxygen was involved.

Comment: Besides being oxidized by singlet oxygen, a dye could act as a quencher for it. The resulting excited triplet state of the dye could prove long-lived enough to be detected spectrophotometrically.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that the singlet oxygen would react with the dye more rapidly than triplet oxygen?